# Cakephp 3.x Insert data into two tables

Tags: cakephp, orm, save, associations, cakephp-3.0

I've two tables: -

**sales**

```
CREATE TABLE `sales` (
    `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `description` text,
    `quantity` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    `price` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `payment_method_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    `user_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**sale_details**

```
CREATE TABLE `sale_details` (
    `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `sale_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    `product_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    `quantity` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    `price` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `total_price` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I need to insert data into these tables accordingly using ajax. First of all, I structured my array data into the following.

Here is my **data**,

```
[
    'quantity' => 3,
    'price' => 63,
    'payment_method_id' => 1,
    'user_id' => 1,
    'sale_details' => [
        0 => [
            'product_id' => 1,
            'quantity' => 2,
            'price' => 24,
            'total_price' => 48
        ],
        1 => [
            'product_id' => 49,
            'quantity' => 1,
            'price' => 15,
            'total_price' => 15
        ]
    ]
]
```

**SalesController.php**

```
if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {

    $sales = $this->Sales->newEntity(
        $this->request->data(), 
        [
            'validate' => 'create',
            'associated' => [
                'SaleDetails' => ['validate' => 'create']
            ]
        ]
    );

    if ($this->Sales->save($sales)) {
        //code 
    }
}
```

<strike>I manage to insert data into those tables but primary key of both tables keep increasing with addition number of 2. I inserted the data for 3 times.</strike> Here is how the data recorded: -

**sales**

```
    id  title   description  quantity  price   payment_method_id  user_id  created              modified             
------  ------  -----------  --------  ------  -----------------  -------  -------------------  ---------------------
     1  (NULL)  (NULL)              3  63.00                   1        1  2017-03-03 11:37:11  2017-03-03 11:37:11
```

**sale_details**

```
    id  sale_id  product_id  quantity  price   total_price  created              modified             
------  -------  ----------  --------  ------  -----------  -------------------  ---------------------
     1        1           1         2  24.00   48.00        2017-03-03 11:37:11  2017-03-03 11:37:11  
     2        1          49         1  15.00   15.00        2017-03-03 11:37:11  2017-03-03 11:37:11
```

<strike>As you can notice from the tables, **sales** table id increasing with the addition of 2 and it happened to **sale_details** table as well.</strike>

**My questions are as following**: -

1) I'm kinda new to cakephp 3, so is this the right method to save data into multiple tables? I removed the following lines and I'm still able to save data into those tables. What to do with 'associated' here?

SalesController.php

```
if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {

    $sales = $this->Sales->newEntity(
        $this->request->data(), 
        [
            'validate' => 'create',
            /*'associated' => [
                'SaleDetails' => ['validate' => 'create']
            ]*/ // removed
        ]
    );

    if ($this->Sales->save($sales)) {
        //code 
    }
}
```

<strike>2) I can't figure out why those id increasing with the addition of 2. I'm pretty sure I've set auto_increment = 1 for both table.</strike>

System variable `auto_increment_increment` has been set to 2. Not sure how could this happen though.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct way to save associations.

Your associations are still being converted (and consequently saved) even without specifying them via the `associated` option, because first level associations are allowed by default, ie when removing the option, all first level associations can be converted, and when specifying it as shown in your example, only `SaleDetails` associations can be converted.

Quotes from the docs:

> By default all the associations on this table will be hydrated. You can limit which associations are built, or include deeper associations using the options parameter

**[API > \Cake\ORM\Table::newEntity()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_newEntity)**

> When you are saving an entity, you can also elect to save some or all of the associated entities. By default all first level entities will be saved.

**[Cookbook > Datbase Access & ORM > Saving Data > Saving Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-associations)**

See also

- **[Cookbook > Datbase Access & ORM > Saving Data > Converting Request Data into Entities](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-request-data-into-entities)**